# Shell script to read filename and pick most recent date by timestamp

Tags: bash, scripts, mysql, backup

I currently backup a MySQL docker container using a shell script, it dumps the mysql file into a relative directory, such as..

```
set-e

TODAY=`date +"%d%b%Y"`

mysqldump -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h $MYSQL_HOST --all-databases | gzip > /data/mysqldb/$TODAY/all-databases-$TODAY.sql.gz
```

I need to create a restore script that will read the $TODAY and determine which is most recent. How do I do this? :S

Comment: If you're going to want to sort textual timestamps, better to use a format that is lexically ordered like `%Y%m%d` or numerically ordered like `%s` - or at least include delimiters so that you can use GNU sort's `M` month sort option for the `%b`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach i used. I have a working backup script with it.

CD into the backup DIR.

```
cd backup_dir && ls -t | head -n 2
```

-t -> sort by modification time, newest first

In a script:

```
LAST_2_BACKUPS=$(ls -t | head -n 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at this too but I was concerned if someone/thing modified something (renamed it for example) it might throw off the automated restore script.

Comment: why would you modify a backup? backups are supposed to be stored in a backup dir or s3 somewhere?

Comment: you have atime and mtime as options too. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-finding-files-by-date/